# What are the rules for resource requests?

Tags: discussion, scope

It seems like a lot of other sites on the Stack Exchange network tend to discourage (or outright ban) requests for off-site resources (tutorial or book recommendations, etc.).

I didn't see anything about that in this site's help center. Are resource requests allowed? If so, what are the guidelines for what constitutes a "good" resource request and what constitutes a "bad" one?

I assume that "can anyone give me a list of *x*..." and purely subjective questions (which translation of *x* is the best?) are off-topic; beyond that, what are the guidelines?

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm actually not sure such a question has been asked yet, and for good reason - they're awfully difficult to do _well_. If you think you can pull it off, I'd encourage you to do so, even if it's going to accrue downvotes.

Comment: Reading recommendation questions are firmly off-topic. http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/q/2/111

Comment: Oh, right. Derp.

Comment: @Hamlet I agree with the answer given on the linked question - the kind of question the OP there's asking about ("what's a good Jane Austin novel to read next?" kind of question) is primarily opinion-based, which just isn't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. (My understanding is that that kind of question is off-topic *everywhere* on the Stack Exchange network).

Comment: @Hamlet I was referring more to resource requests that can be answered in a more concrete way - see [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55943/accurate-surveys-of-urban-pigeon-and-bird-populations), for example.

Comment: If you think you can pull this off, you can start a thread here on meta, along the lines of _Here are some recommendation websites, if you want them_. [Anime and Manga](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/you-want-recommendations-heres-a-list-of-them) did this thing, and it's pretty good.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I don't think these questions need to be phrased as recommendation questions. You could just ask a question about a work of literature, and then say "what is the scholarly consensus on this" if you want works that reference academia.

Comment: @Hamlet That's true. I think that questions asking for specific studies or data or something like that (like the question I linked to on Biology SE) are on topic because the usual reasons for closing resource questions don't apply (it's not opinion-based and doesn't tend to attract opinionated answers or spam).

Comment: [This help centre page](http://literature.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and the links therefrom might be useful to consider. (I'll try to write up an answer here based on that, if I can find the time.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this based on the comments.

"Bad" resource requests tend to be excessively subjective. See, for example, [this question](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/should-recommendation-questions-be-on-topic), which gives some examples of purely opinion-based resource requests ("if I like Jane Austen, who else might I like?"). Purely opinion-based questions are off topic *everywhere* on the Stack Exchange network.

Most importantly, Stack Exchange strives to be a repository of knowledge (not just a forum for discussion or sharing opinions), so good answers should include specific factual or textual evidence. Good questions should be able to be answered in a way that can be factually justified (rather than just soliciting opinions). They should also be useful for future readers.

For example, [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55943/accurate-surveys-of-urban-pigeon-and-bird-populations) on Biology SE is an acceptable resource request because it can be answered in a factual way and is potentially useful for future readers.

"Bad" resource requests tend to attract opinionated answers and spam, and answers can't necessarily be justified in a factual way. Resource requests that are highly localized to your specific situation are also off-topic because they're not likely to be useful to other readers.

Comment: Is the resource request on biology an acceptable question for this site? I don't know; biology and literature have very different standards. There's only one way to tell: ask a question and see what the response is. We can't tell what the consensus is unless we see whether these questions get closed or are left open.

Comment: But I would avoid asking resource request questions if there is a way to get the same answers without asking a resource request question. Asking "what is the current scholarly consensus on x" or "here's a question about literature, by the way I only want answers that cite scholarly sources" seems like a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 7):

The thing about resource requests is that 90% of the time, they can be rewritten into more interesting, non-resource-request questions.

Compare the questions "What are some good sources for understanding Calvino's *Invisible Cities*?" and "what is the significance of *Invisible Cities*' chapter structure?"

The first question will result in a list of books and links. Reading answers to the first question won't tell me anything about *Invisible Cities*: I need to go off the site and look at those sources.

However, answers to the second question will explain things about *Invisible Cities*. Good answers will also cite sources about *Invisible Cities*. The second question is a win-win: the OP gets sources, and we get to read interesting answers about an interesting book.

I don't really have a position on whether resource request questions should be closed or left open. But I think 90% of the time resource request questions can be improved by rewriting them to be non-resource-request questions. So therefore, at the very least, I would encourage community members to only ask resource request questions when they are truly necessary.