# Would this be a story-ID question or a resource request?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

I have an ID question about a particular short story I heard on the radio. I remember the whole plot of the story and a lot of verbatim quotes from it. I also *think* I remember the title of the story, and if I'm right, then I've found a reference to it and its author online. But I'm not 100% certain about the title, and there seems to be literally zero information online about the plot of the story with that title.

How should I phrase my question?

- Describe the plot and hope somebody else can find it, probably with the title I'm guessing?
- Describe the plot *and* the title, link to what I found about the story with that title, and hope that somebody else can find enough info about that story to confirm it's the one I'm looking for?

The first option would definitely be on-topic as a story-ID question, but it might be more likely to go unanswered, and eventually I'd probably just post the almost-infoless link I already found and self-accept, in lieu of anything better. The second option is more likely to give me what I actually want (a solid connection between the plot and the title), but would it count as a resource request - "here's a link about this story with this title, can anyone confirm its plot for me" - rather than a bona fide ID question, and if so, would it be on-topic here?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the difference between the two question is, or why the difference is important. I'm pretty sure that the consensus about resource request questions is that they're OK depending on the specifics of the question (https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/644/111).

Comment: @Hamlet I was writing this meta post late at night, so maybe I wasn't clear enough or was just worrying about nothing :-P I guess I'll just post my question in the "resource-request"y form in a day or two if nobody else says anything here.

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but did you get around to asking the question you had in mind? :) What was the reception to it like?

Comment: @Brahadeesh I didn't, but [now I have](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15068/17) :-)