# "Scholarly entry-point" questions should be on-topic, and not considered recommendations

Tags: discussion

LitSE considers recommendation questions [off topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/should-recommendation-questions-be-on-topic). This seems pretty sensible to me; I imagine they generate a lot of vague discussion that doesn't suit a question-answer site.

I propose that requests for scholarly literature on clear, specific topics should be excluded from this. If well-formed, they can be specific questions with clear answers backed by empirical evidence. Conflicting evidence can be argued about in a meaningful technical way.

Possible example questions that might fit this form:

- "What are well-known critical works analyzing the colonial themes in the Herman Melville novel Moby Dick?" Evidence: specific works, citation stats, teaching curricula.
- [Are there any scholarly analyses of the covers of Penguin Classics, Oxford Classics, etc.?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/23167/are-there-any-scholarly-analyses-of-the-covers-of-penguin-classics-oxford-class) This one could have a more carefully worded question if we had a clearer guideline.
- "What was the critical consensus around the early Doctor Who novels?" Evidence: particular newspaper articles or other essays from the timeframe.

Edit: Related questions:
[What are the rules for resource requests?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/534/what-are-the-rules-for-resource-requests) (from comments)

Comment: Related: [What are the rules for resource requests?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/534/17)